# The least number of DAG's out there

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I found a statement in a book that I don't understand, it suggests that the number of DAGs on N nodes can be bounded from below by $$\prod \limits^N_{n=1} 2^{n-1}  = 2^{N(N-1)/2}$$
My way of thinking is, if we have a DAG it should have maximum of N-1 edges. So $2^{N-1}$ should be the number of different subsets of N-1 edges (so it already includes all DAGs with N-2, N-3 edges).

However formula suggest that we still have to multiply this number by number of DAGs that has less edges than N-1, which I can't understand, since we already have all the N-2, N-3 subsets included in $2^{N-1}$.

Comment: Sorry ! I was not answering the right question.

Comment: Ok, now the notation is correct. However, the claim that a DAG  with $N$ nodes would have a maximum of $N-1$ edges is wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a DAG with $N$ nodes can easily have more than $N-1$ edges: for example, let the nodes be $A,B,C$ and edges $A\rightarrow B, B\rightarrow C, A\rightarrow C$.

Fix an ordering of the nodes. Consider only DAGs such that all edges are directed so that that a parent precedes its child in the ordering. Now, the $n$th node has $n-1$ possible parents, thus the edges from nodes $(1,\ldots,n-1)$ can be picked in $2^{n-1}$ ways. The ordering ensures that there will be no cycles, and thus the parents of each node can be selected independently, and the total number of DAGs consistent with the ordering is the product
\begin{equation}
\prod_{n=1}^N 2^{n-1}.
\end{equation}

However, there exist also DAGs that are not consistent with the selected ordering, and thus this number is only a lower bound for the total number of DAGs.

Comment: But why do you multiply the total amount? If you have N nodes you line them up and take all possible edge sets that will be 2^N-1. This number will already include all subsets for n<N. Maybe I didn't understand your answer, but it seems to me that there should be a recursion which i can't see..

Comment: $2^{N-1}$ is only the number of all the possible ways to select the parents of the last node (yes, this contains also the possibility that there are $n<N-1$ of them). However, besides this, there can be edges between the other $N-1$ nodes. Are you sure you understand the definition of a DAG?

Comment: I re-red the definition re-draw it in cascade form and I get it now. Thank you.